# how do you get virtualenv to work in windows

Tags: python, virtualenv

On windows 10, ***virtualenv*** installs but that's where it stops. Using the "one basic command", "virtualenv MyPathandFile", only gives the error: "*'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command"*.

Tried "python virtualenv" or variations of it doesn't work either. These give the message: *"no such file or directory"*  Are there other packages required? It was installed in an administrator cmd window. Tried uninstalling/reinstalling as well.

And finally, is there another, easier way to make virtual environments?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is not in your path. Can you go to your python installation directory and look for a folder called `Scripts`? There should be a `virtualenv.exe` script there. If it is there, add the path to that folder to your `path` environment variable.

You can also try `python -m virtualenv` and see what that returns.

See my `Scripts` folder (notice virtualenv at the bottom):
[image: my Scripts folder]

Comment: It is in the scripts file. and I did try python -m virtualenv I get the 'no module named virtualenv.

Comment: can you try adding the `Scripts` folder to your path and then running `virtualenv` in the terminal?